# Google Apps script "like" in if statement? Wildcards?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some scripting to format cell color.  I would like to use LIKE to search inside the string (cell value).  I am having a hard time finding something that works.  I am very much new to Google Apps Script\Java.

Basically I want an if statement for a cell value, if it contains the word "extra" with anything before or after it.  So it would match for 1extra and extra1, with any number of characters before or after.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try [tag:regex]

Comment: Hi @EvanSullivan, if you could provide a sheet or at least a snapshot of sample data and the expected output you want, then we can provide a more precise answer to your question.

Comment: @NaziA I would envison it like this:
If(testVar is like "*extra*"){Logger.log("Match")
Cell A1 has the value of "Extra credit" and matches
Cell A2 has the value of "123Extra123" and matches.

Comment: @TheMaster I saw regex played around with it some couldn't figure it out.  Had to stop working on this project for now but I am hoping to pick it back up in a day or two.  I'll keep at regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check if a certain string is present, then you can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var A1_A6 = sheet.getRange("A1:A6").getValues();
  // loop values of A1:A6
  A1_A6.forEach(x => {
    // since x is in [x] form, we get its first and only element
    cell = x[0];
    // if cell value has "extra" in it
    // added i modifier since you want to match "123Extra123"
    if(cell.match(/.*extra.*/i))
      Logger.log(`"${cell}" matches.`);
  });
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- `.*` surrounding "extra" means that any number of any character (it will match any string, be it very long, or none at all)
- modifier `i` after `/.*extra.*/` means it will match regardless of the case (case insensitive - e.g. will match even if we want is "extra" and the one in the string is "Extra"). If you want to only match the exact string "extra", remove the `i`.

#### Reference:

- [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: THanks!!! Works!